# Nginx set proxy_send_timeout only if url has specific param in it

Tags: nginx, timeout

I am new with nginx and learning it for now :), I need some help with set proxy_send_timeout, I need to set this only if url has 'stime' in proxy here is what I am doing:

```
if ($arg_stime != ""){
  proxy_send_timeout 15;
  proxy_read_timeout 15;
}
```

but nginx does not start and gives following error:

4901#0: "proxy_send_timeout" directive is not allowed here in default.conf

any suggestions, Thank you

Best regards

Sajid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `proxy_read_timeout`/`proxy_send_timeout` inside `if`, but there is workaround for this.

Here is sample code:

```
server {
    # ...

    error_page 555 = @normal;
    error_page 556 = @stime;

    location / {
        if ($arg_stime != '') {
            return 556;
        }
        return 555;
    }

    location @normal {
        proxy_pass ...;
        # ...other proxy directives...
    }

    location @stime {
        proxy_pass ...;
        # ...other proxy directives...
        proxy_send_timeout 15s;
        proxy_read_timeout 15s;
    }
}
```

We use the idea from “[If is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#What_to_do_instead)” to choose what `location` will proceed our request.

Comment: thx, I am gonna give it a try but one question here I do not get return 556 will make this executed?location @stime {
        proxy_pass ...;
        # ...other proxy directives...
        proxy_send_timeout 15s;
        proxy_read_timeout 15s;
    }